# .count(); is not a function

Tags: javascript, protractor

So I have been trying to understand what I am doing wrong and I don't seem to understand it!

Before I continue here is the code I am trying to work on

```
it('Clicked all remove button', async function () {
    // Im assuming here that `getRemoveButtonDesktop()` returns a promise of web element array.
    let allBtns = await element.all(by.className('btn btn-remove btn-outlined desktop'));
    // ElementArrayFinder.count() returns a promise that is resolved into a number
    let countElement = await allBtns.count();
    console.log('Find buttons: ', countElement)

    for (let i = 0; i < countElement; i++) { // let variables are scoped to the immediate enclosing block denoted by { }
        // ElementArrayFinder.first() returns a promise
        const firstRemoveButton = await detailsSpecs.getRemoveButtonDesktop().first();
        await utils.click(firstRemoveButton);
        await browser.sleep(1000) // sleep 1s
    }
});
```

and the error I am getting is:

```
  1) Details page
       Clicked all remove button:
     TypeError: allBtns.count is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (pagesDesktop\detailsPage.js:208:36)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

What it supposed to do is to count all "allBtns" where it later on will loop depending on how many elements it found but it seems to not knowing that .count is not a function.

EDIT: Im using Protractor with JS.

getRemoveButtonDesktop = `removeButtonDesktop: element.all(by.className('btn btn-remove btn-outlined desktop')),`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: apparently `getRemoveButtonDesktop` method does not return what you expect. please provide a code sample for the method

Comment: @LuninRoman Oh thats odd. What kind of provide code do you need? `console.log(allBtns)` ?

Comment: What does the `getRemoveButtonDesktop();` method looks like?

Comment: what does `getRemoveButtonDesktop` method return? Provide code sample

Comment: Should be updated now @M.Y

Comment: I have now updated what it does: @LuninRoman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, `all` method is [not](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all) Promise-like, so change

```
let allBtns = await element.all(by.className('btn btn-remove btn-outlined desktop'));
```

to

```
 let allBtns = element.all(by.className('btn btn-remove btn-outlined desktop'));
```

`element.all` returns an `ElementArrayFinder` element which contains the `count` method, while `await element.all` returns just a simple array of elements.

Comment: Ahhh there we go! That was actually the solution. Make sense. I assume in that case if its simple array of elements then .length should work in this case?

Comment: Sure. In this case you should revise the whole code then, e.g. `first` method does not exist on array's as well

Comment: Ohh crap! Oh I have to resolve it first into an elementarrayfinder before I can use it kinda?

Comment: you don't need to call `getRemoveButtonDesktop` method to get first, you can just do this: `const firstRemoveButton = allBtns.first()`

Comment: Ohh right! That is actually supersmart and something I have missed aswell! Thank you very very much! :)